# Getting location takes a long time in Android App

Tags: android, android-location

I was developing an android app for a while which used to access the current location of a user and then other things. But meanwhile the latitude and longitude return 0.0 & 0.0 and then after a while, it shows some values. 
I have had used FusedLocationAPI(currently deprecated) and FusedLocationProviderClient API too but got the same result as well. I used LocationManager but no improvements at all. I attached the current code down below.
Could anyone show me a better way to access the location information? Thanks in advance :)

```
private void Locate() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        String[] permits = {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (!PermissionsAs(this, permits)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permits, REQ_CODE);
        }
        return;
    } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            String string = getCompleteAddressString(lattitude, longitude);

            System.out.println(string);

            System.out.println("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(lattitude) + " Lattitude: " + String.valueOf(lattitude) + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + longitude + " " + lattitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sendText(lattitude, longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't request a location update. It returns the last (recent) request by another app. If no other app has requested the location recently, it will return 0. You're also only using the network provider. Use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER | LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

Comment: thanks. but could you be more specific? @TheWanderer

Answer (score 0):

you could use this library, it handles the location providers automatically and give you the best possible location, I'm using it in my application as well and it works well. 
[Location Provider Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7231)